# Jackson e json array

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

Tudo bom pessoal? Estou matando a cabeça já a alguns dias mas sem sucesso.

Preciso inserir no BD informacoes que vem através de JSON.
Acontece que quando vem um array, ele nao quer inserir.

Explicar melhor:

No domínio, tenho a classe cliente:

```
@Entity
public class Cliente
private String nome;
@ManytoMany
private List<Telefone> telefones = new ArrayList<>();

public Cliente() {}

getters e setters
```

E tenho a classe telefone:

```
@Entity
public class Telefone
private String numero;
@JsonIgnore
@ManytoMany
private List<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();

public Telefone () {}

getters e setters
```

criei uma classe Cliente DTO:

```
public class ClienteDTO
private String nome;
private String numero;

public ClienteDTO () {}

getters e setters
```

e no service criei a classe ClienteService que além de alguns métodos tem o seguinte método:

```
public Cliente converteDoDTO(ClienteDTO clienteDTO) {

Cliente c = new Cliente(clienteDTO.getNome());
Telefone t = new Telefone(clienteDTO.getNumero());

c.getTelefones().addALL(Arrays.asList(t));
t.getClientes().addALL(Arrays.asList(c));

}
```

Dessa maneira se eu passar o JSON dessa forma:

```
{
  "nome" : "Teste",
  "telefone" : "123"
}
```

Será incluído no BD.

Porém eu gostaria que fosse da seguinte forma:

```
{
  "nome" : "Teste",
  "telefones" : 
 [
   {"telefone" : "123"},
   {"telefone" : "456"},
   {"telefone" : "789"}
 ]
}
```

Só que seu fizer isso, o "telefones" vem vazio. E no banco só é inserido o nome. Pesquisei e vi que tenho que usar o ObjectMapper, mais ou menos assim:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Telefone> telefones = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, new TypeReference<List<telefone>>(){});
```

Acontece que nao sei onde criar isso. Se é no serivce, no DTO, no Dominio. 
Estou muito perdido. Alguém poderia ajudar? Grato desde já.

Comment: Seu modelo `telefones:telefone` lembra muito mais XML do que JSON propriamente dito. Um modelo mais idiomático nessa notação seria `"telefones": [ "123", "456", "789" ]`

Comment: O problema é que tenho mais informacoes que somente numero.
Meu telefone é assim na verdade: { "numeroDeTelefone" : "1", "tipoDeTelefone" : 2}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que o atributo de uma classe seja serializado, este deverá possuir a anotação **@JsonProperty** ou possuir a função de acesso **get**

Neste caso, bastou escrever a anotação no **DTO** passando uma **collection**.

```
@JsonProperty("telefones")
```